# Get the last 5 distinct values for each ID

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, distinct

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have a table that contains the following entries:

```
 id | postcode | date_created
 ---+----------+-----------------
 14 | al2 2qp  | 2015-09-23 14:46:57
 14 | al2 2qp  | 2015-09-23 14:51:07
 14 | sp2 8ag  | 2015-09-23 14:56:11
 14 | se4      | 2015-09-23 16:12:05
 17 | e2       | 2015-09-23 16:15:35
 17 | fk20 8ru | 2015-09-23 16:28:35
 17 | fk20 8ru | 2015-09-23 16:35:51
 17 | se2      | 2015-09-23 16:36:17
 17 | fk20 8ru | 2015-09-23 16:36:22
 17 | fk20 8ru | 2015-09-23 16:37:04
 17 | se1      | 2015-09-23 16:37:11
 17 | fk20 8ru | 2015-09-23 16:37:15
 17 | se1 8ga  | 2015-09-24 09:52:46
 17 | se1      | 2015-09-24 10:01:19
 17 | hp27 9rz | 2015-09-24 10:05:27
 17 | hp27 9rz | 2015-09-24 10:05:29
 17 | se1      | 2015-09-24 10:19:46
 14 | tn21 8qb | 2015-09-24 14:49:05
 14 | tn21 8qb | 2015-09-24 15:42:45
 14 | tn21 8qb | 2015-09-24 17:38:06
 14 | n4 1ny   | 2015-09-25 14:49:10
```

What I want to achieve is a query that returns the 5 most recent *unique* postcode records for each id:

```
 id | postcode
 ---+---------
 14 | n4 1ny
 14 | tn21 8qb
 14 | se4
 14 | sp2 8ag
 14 | al2 2qp
 17 | se1
 17 | hp27 9rz
 17 | se1 8ga
 17 | fk20 8ru
 17 | se2
```

What would be the best way of achieving this? I've been playing around with subqueries but keep hitting walls when it comes to ordering them whilst doing a `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: As so often, the exact table definition showing data types and constraints would have helped a lot: what you get with `\d tbl` in psql.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter. I'll be sure to include in future posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. The first that comes to mind is to use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    id, postcode
FROM
  ( SELECT id, postcode, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                              ORDER BY MAX(date_created) DESC
                             ) AS rn
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY id, postcode
  ) AS t
WHERE
    rn <= 5
ORDER BY 
    id, rn ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f7d0d/1).

If there are ties, say the 5th, 6th and 7th `postcode` for an `id` have the same `date_created`, only one of them (choice will be arbitrary) will be in the results. If you want all the tied postcodes in those cases, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

---

Another option is to use the `LATERAL` syntax. I'm not sure which will be more efficient, it wil probably depend on the values distribution of the two columns (`id` and `postcode`), i.e. how many distinct ids in the whole table, how many distinct postcodes per id and how many rows per (id, postcode) combinations.

```
SELECT 
    t.id, ti.postcode
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM tablename
    ) AS t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT tt.postcode,
             MAX(tt.date_created) AS date_created
      FROM tablename AS tt
      WHERE tt.id = t.id
      GROUP BY tt.postcode
      ORDER BY date_created DESC
      LIMIT 5
    ) AS ti 
ORDER BY 
    t.id, ti.date_created DESC;
```

Adding an index on `(id, postcode, date_created)` would be a good idea, too - or on `(id, postcode, date_created DESC)`.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube. We've added an index and are now working with your first suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Typically you would have another table (let's name it `tbl`) with all distinct `id` values in separate rows. If you don't, create it:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl AS 
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM postcode ORDER BY id;  -- ORDER is optional
```

Or replace `tbl` with in below query with the same `SELECT` as subquery, but that's (much) more expensive.

If there can be ***many*** rows per `id`, a **recursive CTE** should be fastest:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT t.id, 1 AS rnk, p.*, ARRAY[postcode] AS arr
   FROM   tbl t
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT postcode, date_created
      FROM   postcode
      WHERE  id = t.id
      ORDER  BY date_created DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) p

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.id, rnk + 1, p.*, arr || p.postcode
   FROM   cte t
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT postcode, date_created
      FROM   postcode
      WHERE  id = t.id
      AND    date_created < t.date_created
      AND    postcode <> ALL (t.arr)
      ORDER  BY date_created DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) p
   WHERE rnk < 5
   )
SELECT id, rnk, postcode, date_created
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY id, rnk;
```

Assuming `postcode` to be `text` or `varchar`. There can be issues in this particular query if `postcode` has type modifiers (like `varchar(50)` or similar):

- [Surprising results for data types with type modifier](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116218/surprising-results-for-data-types-with-type-modifier)

An index on `(id, date_created)` is essential for performance with *big* tables:

```
CREATE INDEX postcode_foo_idx ON postcode(id, date_created DESC NULLS LAST);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b786/2)

You can skip [`NULLS LAST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492) everywhere if `date_created` is defined `NOT NULL`.

If substantially more than 5 rows per `id` is a *rare* case, [@ypercube's queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116144/3684) will be faster. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

The difference: my rCTE comes with more overhead, but performance is hardly influenced by older surplus rows (those are not touched in the query). Both of @ypercube's queries have less overhead, but get slower with more rows per `id`.

Basics with links and more explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

If you don't have a table `tbl`, you can use a similar technique to distill distinct `id` from `postcode` in the first place:

- [Query last N related rows per row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25965393/939860)

Comment: @ypercube moved our comments about a possible bug with type modifiers to a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29540/discussion-between-ypercube-and-erwin-brandstetter). Here is the [follow-up question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/116218/3684) resulting from it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. We're working with a small amount of data at the moment so I went initially with ypercube's first query. However, the data will increase substantially so I'm going to try your way also. I haven't worked with recursive before so I'm going to do a little research first. Thanks again.