# Best index for case insensitive match on one field and ordering by another field

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, order-by

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "core_user"
WHERE UPPER("core_user"."email"::text) = UPPER('emailsearch@example.com')
ORDER BY "core_user"."last_login" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I've tried adding two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX core_user_upper_idx ON public.core_user USING btree (upper((email)::text));
CREATE INDEX core_user_last_lo_0521b8_idx ON public.core_user USING btree (last_login);
```

`core_user_upper_idx` works well if I remove the ordering clause, but in its current state `explain` gives

```
 Limit  (cost=0.29..10.33 rows=1 width=431)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using core_user_last_lo_0521b8_idx on core_user  (cost=0.29..5531.53 rows=551 width=431)
         Filter: (upper((email)::text) = 'EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM'::text)
```

which doesn't perform very well.

Is there a better index for me to add here? I'm a bit unsure as to whether I should "prioritise" the `email` or `last_login` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [multicolumn expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) should serve your particular query best:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.core_user (upper(email), last_login DESC);
```

If `last_login` can be NULL, consider `NULLS LAST` - in index *and* query.
The rule of thumb is: *equality first, range later*. See:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)
- [Get the last 5 distinct values for each ID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116142/get-the-last-5-distinct-values-for-each-id/116159#116159)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! NULLS LAST works well too

Comment: The `DESC` is not necessary.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Not necessary, but if `last_login` can be NULL and the OP meant `DESC NULLS LAST` to begin with, it's faster that way.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Just stumbled across another fine post of yours, addressing the case exactly: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254761/3684